# JavaScript How to create elements into each created element?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, createelement

I'm trying to put a content div into each parent div, but this way it puts all the content divs to the first parent div, not each parent div. I've tried to do it in 2 for loops, tried forEach, but just can't figure it out.

```
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
           const parent = document.createElement("div");
           parent.classList.add("parent");
           parent.setAttribute("id","parent");
           document.getElementById("container").appendChild(parent);
           const content = document.createElement("div");
           content.classList.add("content");
           document.getElementById("parnet").appendChild(content);
        }
```

Ty for your answer

Comment: you are giving all the parents the same ID. Try to make them different, eg by using `\`parent_${i}\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `id`'s to select your parents with. But you can't have multiple elements with the same `id` value. `getElementById` will also look for the *first* occurence of the `id`, so you will **always** get the first parent element.

Besides that, you already have a reference to the parent in your `parent` variable. No need to look it up *again*, just use the reference you already have.

```
const container = document.getElementById("container");

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  const content = document.createElement("div");
  content.classList.add("content");

  const parent = document.createElement("div");
  parent.classList.add("parent");

  parent.append(content);
  container.append(parent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I really didn't realize that I can only use id once, I was so focused on how to add a child to each